# How do you beat the rocky boss guy?

Tags: bloons-monkey-city

There is a boss battle that I tried a while ago. you had to beat this guy who was in a rock-like track. I was dealing damage, but he seems to regen it back. I was using a Supermonkey. Is my strategy not a good one?

Comment: Well, to begin with, your description is rather vague "beat this guy who was in a rock-like track" is not very helpful. All of the special missions in Monkey city have unique icons on your map and are named. Do you perhaps mean this mission: [ZZZZOMG](http://bloons.wikia.com/wiki/ZZZZOMG)?

Comment: No, it looked like a giant blimp, but was covered with rocks. I forgot the name of the mission, sorry. It was kind of like Bloonarius, except not a swamp tile.

Comment: Oh, I see, ok. I know what it is you are talking about now.

Comment: Probaly Dreadbloon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The boss in question is [Dreadbloon: Armored Behemoth](https://bloons.fandom.com/wiki/Dreadbloon:_Armored_Behemoth). It starts with a ceramic layer that will 'regrow' three times (each time its HP meter reaches one of the skull indicators). At higher levels it will regain some ceramic armor even between the regrowth points.

Once the ceramic layer is breached, Dreadbloon has the properties of a Lead Bloon, meaning it cannot normally be damaged by sharp projectiles, or even a Super Monkey's laser blasts (the plasma vision and Sun God upgrades should allow a Super Monkey to damage it). Use of a Monkey Village with the X/3 upgrade (Monkey Intelligence Bureau) would also allow all towers within the Village's range to damage Dreadbloon in it's lead state.

Answer (score -1):

When I battled it, I used a 2-2 dartling gun (you need depleted bloontonium darts to damage it in its lead form) you should be able to beat him, even on l.v. 2, you should only need to battle him twice.